# Macro for pictures with generated labels

Tags: macros, diagrams, labels, plot

Good day,

I would like to write a macro (using Latex3/expl3) that posts pictures and can take several key-value parameters for generated labels/captions etc. I already found code that can do this, but passing generated labels does NOT work.

It started in this thread:
[\ref with macro as parameter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302696/ref-with-macro-as-parameter)

This is code of macro that takes general key-value parameters for placing a plot(works if I use \addpic with hardcoded label):

```
%usage example
% \addpic{
  % width=0.3,
  % image=example-image,
  % caption={This is an example image, and a comma in the caption},
  % label=one,
% }

% \addpic{
  % placement=bp,
  % width=0.2,
  % options={angle=90},
  % image=example-image-a,
  % caption=Rotated image,
  % shortcaption=In the text the image is rotated!,
  %}


\ExplSyntaxOn

% the user level command
\NewDocumentCommand{\addpic}{m}
 {
  \group_begin: % localize the changes to the variables
  \simonson_pic:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

% the key-value interface
\keys_define:nn { simonson/pic }
 {
  placement .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_placement_tl,
  placement .initial:n = htp,
  width .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_width_tl,
  width .initial:n = 1,
  options .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_options_tl,
  image .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_image_tl,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_simonson_pic_label_tl,
 }

% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \simonson_pic:n
 {
  % set the keys from the argument
  \keys_set:nn { simonson/pic } { #1 }
  % start the figure environment
  \__simonson_start_figure:V \l_simonson_pic_placement_tl
  \centering
  % include the image
  \__simonson_pic_image:VVV
    \l_simonson_pic_width_tl % the text width fraction
    \l_simonson_pic_options_tl % other options
    \l_simonson_pic_image_tl % the image name
  % the caption
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl
   {
    \caption{\l_simonson_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   {
    \caption[\l_simonson_pic_shortcaption_tl]{\l_simonson_pic_caption_tl}
   }
   % the label
     In \ addpics \ macro:\ label=\l_simonson_pic_label_tl %for test(my code)
   \tl_if_empty:NF \l_simonson_pic_label_tl
    {
     \label{\l_simonson_pic_label_tl}
    }
   % end the figure environment

   %### %for parser to ignore
   \end{figure}
   %###
}

% syntactic sugar: we want some token lists to be expanded before usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simonson_start_figure:n
 {
  \begin{figure}[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__simonson_start_figure:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__simonson_pic_image:nnn
 {
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__simonson_pic_image:nnn { VVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Key requirement is that the code generating labels is located in one place (as macro) b/c I need to refer to generated labels and same code will be used when referencing using several key-valued parameters.

Here is what egreg suggested in first thread (I didn't indicate the final goal though there):

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { strider/label }
 {
  Re        .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_Re_tl, 
  DOF       .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_DOF_tl,
  statsName .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_statsName_tl,
  Re        .value_required:n = true,
  DOF       .value_required:n = true,
  statsName .value_required:n = true,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyref}{m}
 {
  \strider_label:Nn \ref { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\keylabel}{m}
 {
  \strider_label:Nn \label { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \strider_label:Nn
 {
  \keys_set:nn { strider/label } { #2 }
  #1 % will be \label or \ref
   {
    fig \c_colon_str 
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 1 }
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 2 }
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 3 }
    Re \l_strider_label_Re_tl DOF \l_strider_label_DOF_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{X}
\keylabel{statsName=Strouhal,DOF=4M, Re=50} % just to experiment

This gives a number: \keyref{statsName=Strouhal,DOF=4M, Re=50} (should be 1)

\end{document}
```

This does work, though don't see how to use \keylabel for passing label as parameter to \addpic. \addpic macro will rearly be used on document level (rather used in other macros that will generate label and caption) hence I would like to keep it as general as possible.
Document level macro:
sample call:

```
\myplotFF{file={\plotsPathReFifty/StrouhalNumber},Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}
```

Macro:

```
\keys_define:nn{myPlot}{ 
Re .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_Re_tl, 
DOF .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_DOF_tl,
statsName .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_statsName_tl,
file .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_file_tl,
height .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_height_tl,
label .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_label_tl,
path .tl_set:N = \l_myPlot_path_tl
```

}

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myplotFF}{m}{
        \keys_set:nn{myPlot}{#1}
            \addpic{

                width=0.6,
                %height=0.6,
                image=\l_myPlot_file_tl,
                caption=\getCaption{statsName=\l_myPlot_statsName_tl,
                DOF=\l_myPlot_DOF_tl, 
                Re=\l_myPlot_Re_tl},
                     label=\keylabel{statsName=\l_myPlot_statsName_tl,DOF=\l_myPlot_DOF_tl,Re=\l_myPlot_Re_tl},
            }
}
```

line with 'label=...' doesn't work of course, but if I pass a hardcoded label there it all works. Thats what the first thread all about.
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what the final goal is.

Comment: You probably ask about motivation? If yes, then the one goal is to be able to change plot captions in one place (i.e. only change onemacro that generate captions).  Also using few macros allows to keep all paths in one place and therefore change it easily if necessary. Another is that placing a plot with single line like this:
\myplotFF{file=\plotsPathReFifty/StrouhalNumber},Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}
improves readability for me.

Comment: No, I'm asking for the proposed syntax and the intended output.

Comment: Can you give example? still don't understand

Comment: *You* should give an example of what the macros should do.

Comment: How are all the different bits of code supposed to fit together?

Comment: @cfr That is what I'm trying to figure out myself: is there a way to use egreg's code inside myplotFF macro for generating label.

Comment: @egreg please see cfr's example below.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood what you want correctly, then you would like the following input

```
\section{X}
\myplotFF{file={example-image-a},Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}
```

to produce the following output

[image: target output (possible)]

The code as you currently have it is a mess. You seem to have multiple modules for one package/class/ and multiple sub-modules for handling the same options/data. This is not a good strategy. The whole point of the expl3 syntax is consistency and a hodgepodge of muddled sets of key-value pairs makes for wildly inconsistent code.

Note that this is not a criticism of the original answers. It is, rather, a problem created by attempting to throw quite different instantiations of related functions at each other in the hope that things will stick together to form a harmonious whole. This is a bit like letting a bunch of two-year olds lose in your living room with three or four sets of nicely coordinated paints which clash horribly in combination and hoping the toddlers' sense of aesthetics will combine them into a pleasing result. The fault does not lie in any of the coordinated colour schemes, but in the attempt to combine them using toddler methodology. The result ain't going to be pretty.

I've standardised on `strider` as the main module with `strider/pic` as the sole sub-module. I'm not sure the sub-module is helpful or necessary, but I don't know what the bigger picture is, so perhaps there is a reason for it.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\pdfminorversion=7
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% the key-value interface
\keys_define:nn {strider/pic} {
  Re .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_Re_tl,
  DOF .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_DOF_tl,
  statsName .tl_set:N = \l_strider_label_statsName_tl,
  file .tl_set:N = \l_strider_file_tl,
  height .tl_set:N = \l_strider_height_tl,
  Re        .value_required:n = true,
  DOF       .value_required:n = true,
  statsName .value_required:n = true,
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_strider_pic_caption_tl,
  placement .tl_set:N = \l_strider_pic_placement_tl,
  placement .initial:n = htp,
  width .tl_set:N = \l_strider_pic_width_tl,
  width .initial:n = 0.6,
  options .tl_set:N = \l_strider_pic_options_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_strider_pic_shortcaption_tl,
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \strider_label:N
{
  #1 % will be \label or \ref
  {
    fig \c_colon_str
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 1 }
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 2 }
    \tl_item:Nn \l_strider_label_statsName_tl { 3 }
    Re \l_strider_label_Re_tl DOF \l_strider_label_DOF_tl
  }
}
% the main command
\cs_new_protected:Nn \strider_pic:
{
  % start the figure environment
  \__strider_start_figure:V \l_strider_pic_placement_tl
  \centering
  % include the image
  \__strider_pic_image:VVV
  \l_strider_pic_width_tl % the text width fraction
  \l_strider_pic_options_tl % other options
  \l_strider_file_tl % the image name
  % the caption
  \tl_if_empty:NT \l_strider_pic_caption_tl
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_strider_pic_caption_tl
    {
      statsName:~\l_strider_label_statsName_tl,~DOF:~\l_strider_label_DOF_tl,~Re:~\l_strider_label_Re_tl
    }
  }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_strider_pic_shortcaption_tl
  {
    \caption{\l_strider_pic_caption_tl}
  }
  {
    \caption[\l_strider_pic_shortcaption_tl]{\l_strider_pic_caption_tl}
  }
  \strider_label:N \label
  % end the figure environment

  %### %for parser to ignore
\end{figure}
%###
}
% syntactic sugar: we want some token lists to be expanded before usage
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__strider_start_figure:n
{
  \begin{figure}[#1]
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__strider_start_figure:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__strider_pic_image:nnn
{
  \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,#2]{#3}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__strider_pic_image:nnn { VVV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\myplotFF}{m}{
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set_known:nn { strider / pic } {#1}
    \strider_pic:
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyref}{m}
{
  \keys_set_known:nn { strider / pic } { #1 }
  \strider_label:N \ref
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{X}
\myplotFF{file={example-image-a},Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}

See figure \keyref{Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}

\myplotFF{file={example-image-b},Re=48,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag,caption={Override caption in this case} }

See figure \keyref{Re=50,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag} and \keyref{Re=48,DOF=4M, statsName=Drag}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

The above code has been edited to demonstrate that the label *is* being automatically generated already! To show this, I've added back a very slightly modified version of `\keyref` so that the label can easily be illustrated in the output.

## EDIT EDIT

Further edit to streamline a bit more and provide optional override for caption.

[image: example with references and override]

Comment: Yes, your example is what I need to achieve. Thank you for code suggestions! I am new to expl3 and didn't even use latex for last 10 years or so, feel free to suggest anything. 
The main issue now what to do with labeling. The last 3 parameters in myplotFF determine image uniquely, therefore I'm trying to use them for generating unique label. Another approach is to pass a hardcoded label each time.

Comment: BTW, addpic macro code I took from internet, can barely understand it. Therefore I put it separately in first post.

Comment: "Note that really, there is too much substantive stuff in the code for the user-level macro, so there is plenty of room here for further stream-lining and standardisation"
Not sure I understand this. Should I provide more information? If so, which one?

Comment: @strider My code automatically generates the label from those 3 pieces of information already, so I'm not really sure what further you are trying to do. I've edited the example a bit to make this clearer, but I've left the label-auto-generation alone as I don't understand what is missing.

Comment: @strider It is mostly that I think one of the expl3 people will tell me off for setting the caption in the document-level command rather than in the underlying macros. Since I don't understand expl3 well at all yet, I'm a bit cautious about using it in answers. Especially when egreg's code is being used in the question ;).

Comment: @strider I've taken the caption stuff out of the document-level macro and streamlined a bit by combining the key setting. This version also allows you to override the auto-generated caption, should you need to do so. However, you really need to do some background reading if you are using this stuff. Just looking at examples you find on the internet is unlikely to ensure you understand the basic idea and structure of the syntax. At least, I only started to understand it when I did a bit of reading. `interface3.pdf` is the key document from the `l3kernel` material.

Comment: @cfr For me, on the other side, it was reading internet examples when my mind did *click* and understood the basics of expl3. But, you are right, he should read the documentation.

Comment: @Manuel It may be that you need to read both and that the order isn't crucial ;). I'm not saying I'd have understood *solely* from the documentation, but only that I didn't understand *without* it. Actually, egreg helped me a bit in chat, too, with a couple of examples. But I think the documentation enabled me to identify particular things I didn't get!

Comment: @cfr sorry, didn't notice labeling code at first. Thank you very much! Especially like overiding caption option!

Comment: @cfr For my purpose its better to have caption generating code inside \myplotFF macro, since then I can make several user-level macros with different codes for caption generation. I have a print of your previous version. Can I just 3 lines starting with 
\tl_set:Nn \l_strider_pic_caption_tl {
back to \myplotFF macro?

Comment: @strider Well, officially that's not the 'correct' way. But, yes, you can. You don't need a print out. If you click on the `edited` link, you can see all previous versions of my answer.

Comment: @strider You need the 5 lines starting with `\tl_if_empty:NT \l_strider_pic_caption_tl` if you want the override to work.